# Why does Javascript's Intl.NumberFormat API use 21 as the max value for `maximumSignificantDigits`?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, internationalization

In the Javascript [NumberFormat API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat), there is a `maximumSignificantDigits` option, which is not allowed to exceed 21.

My question is: why 21?

This limit seems especially odd to me given that, as I understand it, all Numbers in JS are 64 bit floats, which can only encode up to 17 significant decimal digits.

Comment: I imagine this is linked to how [`Number.prototype.toPrecision` is only required to support a precision of 21](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision#Exceptions)

Comment: @Eric Yeah, there are other APIs with the same limit... but of course that still begs the question of how those APIs ended up that way :P